# Fork a gitlab repo, simple way to pull merge requests from original into fork?

Tags: git, gitlab, kicad

Question specific to GitLab.

The KiCad footprints repository has currently over 400 open merge requests:

https://gitlab.com/kicad/libraries/kicad-footprints/-/merge_requests

I created a fork of the repo and, besides my own additions, want to add as many of the origin merge requests as viable to create an easier way to review the parts. Is there a way to merge parent merge requests in my fork in bulk or with one or two clicks per request?